# How to run action on different CCDrawNodes at the same time in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a list of [CCDrawNode](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/db/df9/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_draw_node.html) `vector<CCDrawNode*> nodeList;`
,now I want all nodes run an action at the same time. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, try following code:

```
 for(auto it=nodeList.begin();it!=nodeList.end();it++){
     CCSprite *asd=*it;
     asd->runAction();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate for all nodes in vector and run action on every nodes. Actions start in the same frame.